# How to update multiple datas submitted from html form to the respective ids in the database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have the table retrieve from database. Each row have its own action column where there is radio button like po,ao,rac,rap,cancel,hold and ids are supplied via hidden field. How can I loop through all the datas and all respective ids to update in the database.My Database table name is docs where radio button values should submit updated in payment_comment field in database: I dont understand how to loop through all respective ids and update in database.

Here is my view:

```
<form action="payment_prepared" method="POST">
@csrf
  <input type="submit" name="submit">

      <div class="table-responsive">

        <table class="table custom-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">
                <label class="control control--checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="js-check-all"/>
                  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                </label>
              </th>
              <th scope="col" >S.N</th>
              <th scope="col">LC NO</th>
              <th scope="col">Applicant</th>
              <th scope="col">Doc Value</th>
              <th scope="col">Doc Received date</th>
              <th scope="col">LC Type</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php $number = 1;?>
            @foreach($datas as $items)
              
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" style="padding:20px">
                <label class="control control--checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox"/>
                  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                </label>
              </th>
              <td>{{$number}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->lc_no}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->applicant}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->doc_value}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->rec_date}}</td>
              <td>{{$items->sight_usance}}</td>
              
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$items->id}}">
    <td>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="pmt_msg" value="PO"> PO
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="pmt_msg" value="AO"> AO
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="pmt_msg" value="Rac"> RA/C
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="pmt_msg" value="rap"> RA/P
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="pmt_msg" value="cancel"> Cancel
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="pmt_msg" value="hold"> Hold
    </label>

  </td>



            </tr>
            <?php $number++; ?>
            @endforeach
         
            
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      </form>
```

MY controller

```
function payment_prepared(Request $req){

            $data = $req->all();
                foreach($data as $ids){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply prefix your names like this :

```
 <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="items[{{ $item->id}}][pmt_msg][]" value="PO"> PO
    </label>
```

and then in your controller :

```
foreach($req->items as $item){
    //$item[pmt_msg]...
}
```